# TypeError: Only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), tf.newaxis (`None`) and scalar tf.int32/tf.int64 tensors are valid indices, got 'y'

Tags: tensorflow, classification

I am experimenting with binary classification. My dataset is highly imbalanced. **33% belong to Class 1** and **67% in Class 2**.
To compute loss, I am using **tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits** and the code is the following.

```
# Setting up a loss function
labels = tf.reshape(labels['y'], [-1, NUM_CLASSES])

#Using tf.cast to convert label type from int32 to float32, as logit is off type float32
labels = tf.cast(labels, tf.float32) 

loss = tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits(
            targets = labels,
            logits = net_output_ops['logits'],
            pos_weight = 0.49,
            name=None)
```

Using this code, I get the following error: 
**TypeError: Only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), tf.newaxis (`None`) and scalar tf.int32/tf.int64 tensors are valid indices, got 'y'**. My queries are the following:

1. Should I use one_hot_label instead of a label? Though one_hot_label returns the same error
2. I am computing pos_weight = 1/(0.67/0.33) = 0.49, is it correct?
3. And how can I solve this error?

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thank you.